# Top link bar in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

Is there a way in Sharepoint 2010 to show and hide different links in the Sharepoint Top Link Bar depending on which user is logged in.

Answer (score 1):

No.  That's not the way it was designed.  You can make your own header bar links webpart and add it to the masterpage in the place of the existing one and then put whatever you want in there.  We've done that (or something similar) on applications that I've been on.

Comment: very new to this stuff, how would you go about doing that? any examples or resources you can link to?

Comment: You go to visual studio and add a new visual web part.  Edit the masterpage in Designer to add the webpart to the page, and then on the custom webpart you add...whatever, to the .ascx content; much like you would for a traditional ASP.NET application.